# Как распарсить данный json

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, spring-boot, gson

Как распарсить данный json, внести значеия в бд, java, spring boot.

Если бы было без `{"data": [`

я бы создал сущность, пометил бы еще entity,  с полями name, last name и с помощью
gson библиотеки

```
 String json = null;
     json = getJson(
                            "url ");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Gson gson = new Gson();

                Person person = gson.fromJson(json, Person.class);
```

далее `entitymanager.save(person)`

сам json

```
{"data": [{"name": "vasy",
              "lastmane": "vasychkin"}]}
```

Понимаю что нужно по идеи создавать еще одну сущность в которой будет массив с сущностями person, и тоже как-то заносить, или как?

Comment: Глядя на пример json, я бы сказал, что с т.з. БД есть таблица `data` с двумя столбцами -- `name` и `lastname`

Comment: я делал 2 сущности, в первой дата во второй person, и соотношение один к многим, и получается в таблицу персон хочу добавит все значение name, lastname и колонки id сущности data? но не могу распарсить

Comment: У вас первый класс должен содержать одну переменную `List<Person> data` , а класс `Person` два `String` `name` и `lastname`. Тогда данные должны замапиться. Нужны ли какие-либо аннотации над ними и пустой конструктор для Gson не помню.